# IE10 unable to open Sharepoint document

Tags: office-integration

I have Win8, IE 10, Office 2010, trying to open/edit document from Sharepoint 2007, and I received:
"The document could not be opened for editing. A Windows Sharepoint services compatible application could not be found to edit the document"

This happened ever since I used a new machine.  Previously there was no problem to access the same files using Win7 IE9 & Office 2007.

I have done the followings to troubleshoot but still no good:
1. Make sure IE 10 is running in 32bit mode
2. Checked the Adds-on and the SharePoint Export Database Launcher, SharePoint OpenDocument Class, and SharePoint Stssync Handler are all enabled

Anyone got the similar issue?  Appreciate to any help.

Comment: Try to add your Sharepoint site in IE10 Compatibility view. Sorry, not the answer, just giving suggestions.

Comment: I have got the same issue, and it works after adding site to compatibility issue. i have tested pc with IE addon SharePoint OpenDocument Class has 32 and 64bit does not work. But it only works with same Addon of 32bit.